# Getting error while trying to debug vscode source from vsode - Error: Cannot find module 'winreg'

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug vscode source code from vscode itself. While I am trying to debug from the 'Launch VS Code' and press F5, it gives the following error.

```
Loading "winreg" failed
loader.js:224
Error: Cannot find module 'winreg'
loader.js:227
at Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (c:\Users\oguz\Documents\workspace\vscode\.build\electron\resources\electron.asar\common\reset-search-paths.js:35:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at nodeRequire (file:///C:/Users/oguz/Documents/workspace/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:1642:28)
at NodeScriptLoader.load (file:///C:/Users/oguz/Documents/workspace/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:703:39)
at OnlyOnceScriptLoader.load (file:///C:/Users/oguz/Documents/workspace/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:549:37)
at loadNextPath (file:///C:/Users/oguz/Documents/workspace/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:1401:41)
at Object.errorback (file:///C:/Users/oguz/Documents/workspace/vscode/out/vs/loader.js:1409:25)
Detail: 
loader.js:225
Error: Cannot find module 'winreg'
loader.js:225
Here are the modules that depend on it:
Array(1) ["vs/platform/telemetry/node/workbenchCommonProperti…"]
```

Comment: Any comments yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my own solution. Npm requires `winreg` module but it could not find it. So, I installed it manually by `npm install winreg` command. Now I can debug vscode.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/winreg